# Paypal delay to send notify_url function

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using `Paypal` to receive my customers pays and set the "notify_url" in my form like

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="www.mywebsite.com/PayPalNotify" />
```

and i test it with sandbox account the notify function run but after about 30 to 240 minutes can any one tell me if this delay because i am using sandbox or it's normal in `Paypal` Payment

Comment: It's called Instant Payment Notification, but it isn't. It can take an undefined amount of time. Normally pretty quick but you can't build your application around 'normally'.

Comment: Agree with @EJP. In my own experience the notification comes pretty fast but If you rely on time then you better use PayPal Express Checkout.

Comment: _"Because IPN is not a real-time service, your checkout flow should not wait for the IPN message before it is allowed to complete. If the checkout flow is dependent on receiving an IPN message, processing can be delayed by system load or other reasons. You should configure your checkout flow to handle a possible delay."_ REF: [Paypal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)